# Pine Script: horizontal line above previous day close price

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to create a pine script indicator which draws horizontal line 100 points above based on the previous day close price.

E.g.
If Previous day close price is 1500, i want horizontal line "100 points above previous day close price" i.e. at 1600

Comment: What have you tried so far and where do you need help?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("request.security")

prev_day_close =request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
new_day_custom_price = prev_day_close + 100
hline(new_day_custom_price, title = "Previous Day + 100")
```

Comment: it says line 9: Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='new_day_custom_price'. An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'input float' is expected

Answer (score 0):

//@version=5
indicator("horizontalLine", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 10)
line.new(bar_index[1], close[1] + 100 , bar_index, close[1] + 100, extend = extend.right)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).